# How to use Case Condition in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

how to convert case statement SQL query to Sequelize. I tried but it's not working for me

Imported my models here

```
const Proj = require('/models/Project');

Proj.findOne({
  attributes:[
    'Proj',
    [Sequelize.literal(`CASE Type WHEN 'Project_Name' THEN Project_Name : ${req.body.Project_Name}`),
    'Project'
  ],
  ...
]);                               

Now error:

    "error ReferenceError: models is not defined"
```

Comment: have you imported models correctly? Please post more code and the whole stack trace.

Comment: here is my code # user8810865

Comment: why don't you compare after making both as lower case?

Answer (score -1):

Import model as follows:

```
const Proj = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/Project');
```

Hope this help.